# Direct2D/DirectX rasterization rule for lines

Tags: directx, direct2d

I've read the online docs about DirectX rasterization rules but I still can't understand why doesn't this code produce anything visible on the screen?

> target->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED);
>   target->DrawLine(D2D1::Point2F(0.f, 0.f),
>   D2D1::Point2F(10.f, 0.f), redBrush, 1.f);

Of course, if I change y from 0.0f to 1.0f for both line points I get a visible horizontal line at the top-left side of the Window client area but I would like to understand what principles are involved here. I couldn't figure them out from available documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should draw your line "in the middle of the pixel":

```
target->DrawLine(D2D1::Point2F(0.0f, 0.5f), D2D1::Point2F(10.f, 0.5f), redBrush, 1.f);
```

Otherwise, if you don't use antialiasing, your line can be drawn on either side 0/0...10/0 line. In your case it gets drawn outside of window canvas.

Note that pixel on screen is actually a rectangle with coordinates `D2D1::Point2F(0.0f, 0.0f)` to `D2D1::Point2F(1.0f, 1.0f)`.

And `D2D1::Point2F(0.5f, 0.5f)` is the center of that rectangle. If you draw 1x1 rectangle around that coordinate it will cover the pixel exactly.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I was reading on rasterization rules which use the coordinate system not in use in DirectX 10 and later:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/rasterization-rules

Comment: Are the new, so-called diamond area rules in force for aliased lines in DirectX 10 and later?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-rasterizer-stage-rules

Comment: These are common "rules" used by Direct2D, Skia, Cairo, GDI+. In aliased rendering pixel gets drawn if its center happens to be inside the outline and so is a matter of computational precision.  One pixel line as defined in your case is a rectangle  from 0, -0.5 (inclusive) to 10.0, +0.5 (exclusive). Thus pixels in the zero row of the bitmap are not touched by rendering.

Comment: I understand, now that I am not taking 0,0 as a topmost, leftmost pixel center, as was in DirectX 9. However, are you sure about GDI+? Namely, the other reason for my confusion is that in GDI+ a code like graph.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 10, 0); for 1.0 wide pen *does* produce a visible line, both in aliased and anti-aliasing mode.

Comment: It depends on particular conventions, GDI+ may interpret line as a rectangle starting at 0,-0.5 exclusive and end at 10.0,+0.5 inclusive. D2D apparently works more correct in this respect. In general, when you work with aliased primitives you should switch to FillRectangle() rather then using DrawLine(). Other option is to set `m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(0.5, 0.5));` before drawing but that is tricky if to think about higher than 96 dpi surfaces.